# Jquery filter returned select

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am a beginner with jquery.
I want to show only the first 5 rows of tables with the class filter.
I tried the beneath statement but it doesn't work.

```
$('.filter').('tr').slide(5).hide()
```

When is use `$('.filter tr').slice(5).hide()` he shows only the first five TR's of the first table on the page.
What is the best way to archive this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just iterate the list:

```
$('.filter').each(function() { $(this).find('tr').slice(5).hide(); });
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use `:nth-child` selector with a proper equation [Docs][1].

```js
$('.filter tr:nth-child(n+6)').hide()
```

```css
table {
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="filter">
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>7</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<table class="filter">
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>7</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<table class="filter">
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>7</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<table class="filter">
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>7</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

[1]: http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/

```
$('.filter tr:nth-child(n+6)').hide()
```